# Как добавить подкатегорию в объекте?

Tags: php, объекты

Как правильно добавить подкатегорию в объекте?

```
$F = new stdClass();
$F->name = "Vasy";
$F->age = 12;
$F->sub->fhone = "08945";
```

Ошибка:

> Warning. Creating default object from empty value

Answer (score 3):

Вы обращаетесь к `sub`, как объекту, хотя его даже не создали. Очевидно этот узловой объект надо создать

```
$F = new stdClass();
$F->name = "Vasy";
$F->age = 12;
$F->sub = new stdClass();
$F->sub->fhone = "08945";
```

либо так:

```
// php >= 5.4: $F->sub = (object) ['fhone'=>'08945'];
$F->sub = (object) array('fhone'=>'08945');
```